# Extending a theme: build new features as plugin or core modules?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, themes

I have developed my own WordPress theme based on the Roots starter theme. Because of my clients needs, I'm often required to develop custom features (what I refer to as "modules") that are added to the core: for example a "Projects" custom post type, a "Business Hours" page in the admin, or a custom "Slider" menu, etc.

There's a couple reasons why I decided to code these modules and extend the theme instead of using existing plugins:

- It's a great way to learn WordPress
- I need to bundle and activate the modules dynamically in every new projects
- I don't want the clients to be able to deactivate the features (unlike plugins)
- I don't want to rely too much on third-parties
- For consistency matters, I like if the code is similar everywhere
- Flexibility: from my experience home-made modules are often easier to understand, maintain, and improve in the future

I do however understand that building my features as plugins would brings a better code separation and have it's benefits.

So here's my question: **Should I keep building and adding the new features directly to the theme, or develop them as plugins instead?** What is the best approach based on your knowledge and experience?

Any input or documentation would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to want to mix-and-match these modules, I would suggest developing them as plugins or using a plugin such as [Code Snippets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) to separate your modules, making them easier to work on, expand upon, and deactivate/activate.

Either way, separating your modules from your theme will make customizing deployments faster while increasing the organization of your code.

Comment: Great point: I now realize that plugins would be more flexible but there are still a few concerns though:
- How to I prevent the user from deactivating a plugin?
- Is there a better way to require plugins when activating a theme beside the TGM Plugin Activation library? I guess I could always create some kind of script that would activate the theme with the right modules at the start of the project...

Comment: WordPress has filters for just this purpose! You can remove plugin controls for the plugins you specify using the plugin_action_links filter. Here's a [tutorial](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/remove-plugin-deactivation-wordpress/) on how to do it.

For single file plugins that don't have activation hooks, you could place them in mu-plugins, but you may run into issues with that.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, that's good enough to convince me to change my approach :) I'll find a nice plugin boilerplate and give it a shot! Thanks again mate.